# How to use a preprocessed .i file in another C++ program?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have one program that I compile and generate a preprocessed output file, as described at this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

It generates a .i file as an output. Anyone know where I can find an example of properly using this output file in another program?

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with the other files just as a regular source file? Think that should work...

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't realize I can just treat it as a source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocessed files are files which contain all pre-processor substitutions in place. You should just compile them as other source files.

Comment: How can I include it (X.hpp.i file) in another source(.cc/.cpp) file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Wrapper Java, you will be very happy to have this file.
See : http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html